# WebView not loading for any apps?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, sony-xperia, webview

Any app that has an embedded browser in them don't load anything. A few examples: Steam, Telegram, and Relay reddit client all have embedded browsers and none of them load. Firefox works though but I guess it uses a different thing than the system default that the previously mentioned apps do. I'm not sure what things to try to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried updating webview from Play Store?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried uninstalling the already downloaded updates too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, it was an older version of [AdBlocker Reborn](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.aviraxp.adblocker.continued) that was causing the issue. I had the "Enable WebView Block" feature enabled. After updating to the latest version of AdBlocker Reborn, everything worked again.